# Amigo Oculto com PHP

Tags: php

Pessoal estou criando uma lógica para um amigo oculto em PHP.

Estou utilizando o código abaixo para realizar isto:

```
//Definindo nomes para participar do amigo oculto
$nomes=["Matheus","Alice","Claudia","Leo","Emanuel","Joao"];

//Guardo a primeira formação para definir quem irá tirar quem no amigo oculto;
$ori = $nomes;

//Embaralho de forma aleatória os nome mandados. Sempre serão aleatórios
shuffle($nomes);

foreach($nomes as $key => $n) echo str_pad(strtoupper($ori[$key]),"12"," ",STR_PAD_RIGHT) . ' ==> ' . strtoupper($n) . '<br>';
```

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Quando eu uso `foreach(shuffle($nomes) as $key => $n)` eu tenho um erro. Porque eu não consigo colocar função dentro do foreach? Como eu posso entender de maneira prática isto?

Comment: Pode me informar qual seria o erro apresentado ?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(); o Erro consegui entender. Mas eu não entendi porque ele não aceita. Aonde eu tenho mais informações sobre isto do foreach?

Comment: Pelo o que entendo do **foreach**, ele recebe apenas array como parâmetro, já o **shuffle** retorna um boleano, sendo assim o motivo da apresentação desse erro, segue um paragrafo sobre o [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php): '_O construtor foreach fornece uma maneira fácil de iterar sobre arrays. O foreach funciona somente em arrays e objetos, e emitirá um erro ao tentar usá-lo em uma variável com um tipo de dado diferente ou em uma variável não inicializada_.'

Comment: Acontece que a função **shuffle** altera o array alocado na memória. Ela não retorna um novo array. A função apenas retorna se fez isso com sucesso (**true**) ou não (**false**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você cria uma variável no `php` ou em qualquer outra linguagem, esta é armazenada na memória com uma referência para que você possa usar quando necessário.

A maioria das variáveis no php tem escopo local, isso significa que se você fizer isso...

```
$a = ['um', 'dois']; 
alterar($a);
print_r($a);

function alterar($a){
    $a[0] = "1";
    $a[1] = "2";
}
```

... o array `$a` vai continuar a ter o valor `['um', 'dois']` pois na função, ele está em um escopo diferente.

Então, como o **shuffle** faz?

No php, para você alterar uma variável em uma função de um outro escopo, você precisa [usar uma atribuição por referência](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference) com o sinal de `&`.

Isso significa criar uma nova variável com a mesma referência. Veja um exemplo:

```
$a = "olá"; // ola
$b =& $a; // ola

$b = "mundo"; // mundo
echo $a; // mundo
```

A saída será "mundo". Pois ambas as variáveis tem a mesma referência.

Um exemplo na função seria assim:

```
$a = ['um', 'dois']; 
alterar($a); // altera
print_r($a);

function alterar(&$a){ // <-- aqui
    $a[0] = "1";
    $a[1] = "2";
}
```

Agora a saída será:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

Como foi dito pelo @henriquuepedro, o erro acontece porque o shuffle não gera um novo array. Ele apenas altera o array alocado e retorna um boleano.

Comment: Agora consegui entender, muito obrigado. tbm ao colega @henriquuepedro. O foreach sempre vai esperar um array. Muito obrigado. Agora ficou muito claro!

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo exatamente! Tranquilo amigo =)